# How to prove that $|z+c| \le |1+cz|$ if and only if $|z| ≤ 1$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $c$ be a complex number satisfying $|c| < 1$. Demonstrate that $|z+c| \le |1+cz|$ if and only if $|z| ≤ 1$, with equality holding if and only if $|z| = 1$.

Comment: If $c$ is allowed to be non-real, the correct inequality should be $|z+c|\leq|1+\overline{c} z|$.

Answer (score 2):

$$|1+cz|^{2}-|c+z|^{2}=(1+|c|^{2}|z|^{2} + 2Re (\overline {c}z)) -(|c|^{2}+|z|^{2}+2Re (\overline {c}z))$$ $$=(1-|c|^{2})(1-|z|^{2})$$ from which the result follows easily.

Comment: I think you forgot a (+)

Comment: @FareedAF Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

If $|c|< 1$, the function $f(z)=\frac{z+c}{1+\overline{c}z}$ is holomorphic over the unit disk. By the maximum modulus principle, for any $|z|\leq 1$ we have
$$ \left|\frac{z+c}{1+\overline{c} z}\right|\leq \max_{|z|=1}\left|\frac{z+c}{1+\overline{c} z}\right|=1 $$
since $f(z)$ sends the unit circle into itself:
$$ |e^{i\theta}+c| = |1+c e^{-i\theta}| = |1+\overline{c} e^{i\theta}|.$$